# The object is write protected or the server cannot read it

Tags: string, fullcalendar

I have this `var` called `turnosFinal2`

```
 {"title":"Mariel Guerrieri","start":"2020-03-18T09:30:00","end":"2020-03-18T10:30:00"}
,{"title":"Agustin Guerra","start":"2020-03-17T12:30:00","end":"2020-03-17T13:30:00"}
,{"title":"Maria Marco","start":"2020-03-21T13:00:00","end":"2020-03-21T14:00:00"}
```

And a `fullCallendar` with the `events` propierty:

```
    events: [{
        title: 'Agustin Guerra',
        start: '2020-03-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2020-03-12T11:30:00'
    }]
```

In this case, the event is static and it successfully renderized when i load the webpage.. **I wanna replace this static event for dinamic data**

Then, i transform the var `turnosFinal2` on this way:

```
var turnosFinal = "[" + (turnosFinal2.replace(/"title"/g, "title").replace(/"start"/g, "start").replace(/"end"/g, "end").replace(/"/g, "'")) + "]";
```

Getting now:

```
[{title:'Mariel Guerrieri',start:'2020-03-18T09:30:00',end:'2020-03-18T10:30:00'}
,{title:'Agustin Guerra',start:'2020-03-17T12:30:00',end:'2020-03-17T13:30:00'}
,{title:'Maria Marco',start:'2020-03-21T13:00:00',end:'2020-03-21T14:00:00'}
]
```

from my point of view this variable should now be able to go in the value of `events`, so i put it

```
events: turnoFinal,
```

But i get this console error:

> main.js:4329 GET http://localhost/pos/[%7Btitle:'Mariel%20Guerrieri',start:'2020-03-18T09:30:00',end:'2020-03-18T10:30:00'%7D,%7Btitle:'Agustin%20Guerra',start:'2020-03-17T12:30:00',end:'2020-03-17T13:30:00'%7D,%7Btitle:'Maria%20Marco',start:'2020-03-21T13:00:00',end:'2020-03-21T14:00:00'%7D]?start=2020-03-16T00%3A00%3A00-03%3A00&end=2020-03-23T00%3A00%3A00-03%3A00 403 (Forbidden)
>
> main.js:5273 Request failed {message: "Request failed", xhr: XMLHttpRequest}

If i click on first line `(localhost/pos/[%7...)` get this:

> ## ¡Forbidden Access!
>
> You do not have permission to access the requested object.
>              The object is read protected or
>              the server cannot read it.

Comment: "i transform the var turnosFinal2 on this way:"....urgh, this is **not** the way to manipulate JSON data. First, parse the JSON into a Javascript array variable. And then update the properties of the variable in the normal way. Don't mess about trying to do string replacement, it's not necessary, and likely to be error-prone. Also if you are supplying hard-coded data to fullCalendar, it expects you to pass it a proper array, not a string (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array).

Comment: Excuseme, in first place i dont speak  english, im from argentina. Looks like i write like an   alien. In second place, the var ``turnosFinal2`` its a ``string``, how can i transform it in a json object? if i do JSON.parse the debugger throws error. Excuseme again, im so noob with programming

Comment: _"its a string, how can i transform it in a json object"_. It's already a JSON object. JSON is a string format. What I think you mean is: "how can I transform it into a Javascript object". The answer is using `JSON.parse()`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse . Exactly what error does it give you, please?

Comment: Actually though, if you want to get dynamic data, a much better way is to give fullCalendar a URL instead. That URL can point to a script on your server which returns the events in JSON format. (In that setup, fullCalendar will do the JSON.parse() automatically for you when it receives the data from the URL). See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed . This way your server can return the correct data dynamically each time it is requested.

Comment: P.S. If you prefer to speak in Spanish you can visit https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fullcalendar instead.